# How to convert Msword file into a text file and storing it in Mysql - php joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Hey i want to convert MsWord doc file into text file - any code sample.
And then i want to store it to in database MySql - any code.
And also how to retrieve it in a same format tht was in Msword file using php joomla

Comment: Hey! Hang on you posted a question of the same topic an hour ago here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528514/uploading-ms-word-file-in-database-joomla-php What's the reason behind it? Double posting is frowned upon!!!! Voting to close as that is definitely duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding MS Word files:

- DOC files are single binary files
- DOCX files are packages (something like ZIP files containing an XML manifest and multiple binary files).

You would waste a lot of valuable database space storing binary files into blobs.

It may be easier to store the files into a filesystem directory and record the path to the directory in MySQL.